# C# Download file from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I have a web service, like [this example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-files-from-web-api/) for downloading a zip file from the server. When i open the URL through web browsers,I can download the zip file correctly. The problem is when I try to download the zip file through my desktop application. I use the following code to download:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"http://localhost:9000/api/file/GetFile?filename=myPackage.zip"), @"myPackage.zip");
```

After testing this, I get the myPackage.zip downloaded, but it is empty, 0kb. Any help about this or any other server code + client code example?

Comment: just a sanity check here: are you awaiting for your async request to finish?

Comment: is `ProgressChanged` ever called? verify in a debugger. if the thread (or the host process) terminates before the first chunk is transmitted, download will be aborted which would explain the zero size file.

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin Does he need to, though, if he's responding to events?

Comment: May you use the DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync, Just to be sure. And tell us if it fix the issue ?

Comment: I am not using await, it says "Cannot await void". The progress changed isn't called ever, but the Complete yes.

Comment: @KennethK. Good point.  What I'm trying to confirm in a roundabout way is that the process doesn't terminate before the async operation completes.

Comment: I tried using DownloadFile, it gave me an Exception, 400 Bad Request.

Comment: If your getting a **400 Bad Request**, then a) does that URI work correctly in the browser, and b) is there any authentication required for the resource?

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin I suppose the `WebClient` could be being disposed (or rather not disposed), now that I think about it more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to use HttpClient instead. Usually, it is more convenient.

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(@"http://localhost:9000/api/file/GetFile?filename=myPackage.zip");

        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo("myPackage.zip");
            using (var fileStream = fileInfo.OpenWrite())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. (Just as an aside, "convenient" is relative. I could have done all this in one line of code in Perl, using LWP::UserAgent module, but then we have to work with what we have.) :-)

Comment: This is good, though it should be called out that client should be reused rather than making a new instance and disposing after each use.  [This article explains why](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)